# in Laravel How to post data to another route in a route ?

Tags: laravel

I have a Post Route in Laravel, so if a user post data to the route I want to add data to request then posting it to another post route that I have then show the user the result that I get from the second route.
Is there way to do it? or I should use GuzzleHttp?

Comment: Change your vision :) as I understood, you need to only one post-route, well, post your data to it, your controller get request-data, so, you have access to that data, you can call method and pass the data to it, or call another api method and pass data to it, or manipulate the data by your action controller,... you can do any stuff you want and don't need to call another route! :)

Comment: Guzzle is pretty nice for server-side request

Comment: @YaserKH the second route is the third party package so I don't want to change it I just only want to attach data to request and pass data to it.I think to add a middleware is a good option too.

Comment: I'm agree, middleware is a good solution :)

Comment: While Guzzle is technically a way. A better way is to extract the code that handles the other request and call it as a function from both the original route and the one that you need to add extra parameters to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to perform the sub request.

```
Route::any('/proxy', function (Request $request) {

    //Get all of the input from the request and store them in $data. 
    $data = $request->all();

    //initialise your other data. 
    $data2 = ['xyz' => "xyz"];

    $newPayload = array_merge($data, $data2);

    $endPoint = "https://example.org";

    $ch = curl_init($endPoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $newPayload);

    // execute!
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // close the connection, release resources used
    curl_close($ch);

    return (string)$response;
});
```